# GPU/CPU workload is low but games are lagging (Tested PSU) Win10

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, power-supply, gpu, lag

Well I run into this issue after running this system for a few months without any problems. I tried to downgrade my gpu driver, restored windows to a point where the system was fine, checked the psu (replaced with another psu) and still got the same issue. Games are not running smooth, but the gpu/cpu is running at 30%. Oh and yes I checked the power settings, I'm running on "High performance" at the moment.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/hSrJd]

[image: http://imgur.com/a/hSrJd]

Comment: Please tell me how to improve the question, instead of just downvoting :(